# Default username and password on a brand new Dell CMC Blade management chassis

Tags: dell, blade-server

We've just got a brand new Dell M1000e blade chassis ^.^ (Squee!).

We've no idea what the username/login for the Dell CMC manager is.

Anyone know? We've mountains of paper and docs from Dell, and haven't found the answer there yet.

Comment: This link says the default username/password are root/calvin [http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/cmc/cmc1.0/en/ug/html/usinggui.htm]. Did you try that?

Comment: Try username: root; password: calvin

Comment: @Khaled It's much quicker if I ask questions and people give me answers.

Comment: root/calvin seems to be the standard logon for Dell BMC / CMC / DRAC & DRAC/MC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

wikipedia FTW!

username: `root`

password: `calvin`

[Wikipedia page on Dell DRAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC)

Answer (score 5):

Have come across this in the past.

> The default CMC user name is root, and the password is calvin. The
>   root account is the default administrative account that ships with the
>   CMC. For added security, Dell strongly recommends that you change the
>   default password of the root account during initial setup.

Also works for Dell Cloud servers IPMI

Reference [here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/cmc/cmc2_10/en/ug/html/usinggui.htm)